# How to print recursive data structure with Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am trying to print a recursive data structure using Template Toolkit. How can I describe this in my template file?

I have a data structure (Hash Array) with some elements like this

```
ELEMENT
-> Description: XYXY
-> Childs: [Array of Child ELEMENTS of same type]
```

Where childs can contain an array of child elements. I want now recursively print all contents including the elements childs and those childs and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The equivalent of a function is a `BLOCK`. Don't know if they can be called recursively, but it wouldn't surprise me if they could. If not, you can pre-flatten the recursive structure into an array with a depth attached to each element. (`[ [ 0, $root ], [ 1, $child1_of_root ], [ 2, $child1_of_child1_of_root ], ... ]`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `PROCESS` to pass data into a `BLOCK` which you can do recursively. For example:

```
[%

SET element = {
    description = "A",
    children= [
        {
            description= "AA",
            children= [
                { description = "AAA" }
            ]
        },
        {
            description= "AB",
            children= [
                { 
                    description = "ABA",
                    children = [
                        { 
                            description = "ABAA"
                        }
                    ]

                },
                { description = "ABB" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

%]


[% BLOCK show_element %]
    [% my_element.description | html %]
    [% IF my_element.children %]
        <ul>
            [% FOR child_element IN my_element.children %]
                <li>[% PROCESS show_element my_element=child_element %]</li>
            [% END %]
        </ul>
    [% END %]
[% END %]

[% PROCESS show_element my_element=element %]
```

Comment: `PROCESS` uses global versions of your variables.  In some cases it may be necessary to use `INCLUDE` instead, to use local copies for recursion.  Example, if you want to track nesting:  `[% INCLUDE  nesting_level=nesting_level+1 %]` <-- won't work with `PROCESS`.  http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template.html#section_INCLUDE